# OBD2 is giving me a bus init error

Tags: c#, winforms, string, bus, obd-ii

I am working with a C# to build a application that would be similar as the other OBD2 reader applications.

I have tested a OBD2 adapter which is connected troughthe Bluetooth port to my PC. 
I was testing this adapter with the following program "[Torque](http://torque-bhp.com/software/torque-android-obd2-adapters/)" and I must say that program is working really great. I am reading all the parameters.
I was even testing it with the program that makes a virtual COM port on PC and has loop which is giving me some different states and messages and with that my program is working correctly with no errors.

So my problem is occurring when I get first message from my car.

This part of the code actually gets the [PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs) from the car. And in this example PID that I'm getting is in this format : **010D Bus..init error** (I am sure that this is a message but I'm not sure if this is in a original format, maybe one dot more or less).

```
private string GetValue(string pid)
        {
            sp.Write(pid + "\r");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            const int buffSize = 1024;
            bool cont = true;
            int count = 0;
            byte[] bff = new byte[buffSize];
            string retVal = string.Empty;
            while (cont)
            {
                count = sp.Read(bff, 0, buffSize);
                retVal += System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bff, 0, count);
                if (retVal.Contains(">"))
                {
                    cont = false;
                }
            }
            return retVal.Replace("\n", "");
        }
```

Then I go in this function:

```
public int? GetSpeedKmh()
        {
            CheckSerialPort();
            const string obdMessage = "010D";
            if (OnGetSpeedInit != null)
                OnGetSpeedInit(new OBDIIEngineEventArgs(null, obdMessage));
            string data = GetValue(obdMessage);
            int? retVal = (data.Contains("NO DATA")) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(data.Split(' ')[2].Replace("\r>", string.Empty), 16);
            if (OnGetSpeedDone != null)
                OnGetSpeedDone(new OBDIIEngineEventArgs(retVal, obdMessage, data.Contains("NO DATA")));
            return retVal;
        }
```

Now error is occurring in this line:
`int? retVal = (data.Contains("NO DATA")) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(data.Split(' ')[2].Replace("\r>", string.Empty), 16);`

Because I am getting a bus init error msg and it can't determine what is written.

So what can I do to correct this program? Does anyone has a similar problem? I am sure that OBD2 adapter is working, COM port is getting data, and I have tested it with other programs and it is reading all data that I need.

I have tried to google it and I can't find anything that can solve my problem.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving on that line?  What's the value of `data` in the return from `GetValue(obdMessage);`?  Any error you're going to get from the line you've mentioned is going to be related to string manipulation or failure to convert the value to an `int`.  Does `data` really have three parts after you split on the space?

Comment: yes I'm getting string error because I am getting a different string that I should get. And I need to know why am I getting a **Bus initialization error** from my adapter

Answer (score 0):

I see you've got a call to:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
```

in your code.

I don't know anything about interfacing with an OBD2 adapter but it seems like an assumption is being made here that 100ms is enough time to for that `sp.Write(pid + "\r")` call to take place.  What happens if you bump that up to 200ms?  500ms?

Seems like your code is relying upon things happening within a given amount of time and that might, in fact, not be long enough for that action to take place.

Comment: hi, actually I have this part of the code that is calling my function on every 600ms. Code `while (td.IsAlive){           eng.GetSpeedKmh();}`

Comment: I'm assuming that `sp.Write` refers to a `SerialPort.Write()` call.  Is that correct?  If so, do you have the serial port configured correctly, like baud rate and such?  Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx